# Spring Jpa date filter not working properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have field effective_startdate in my Entity class.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
@Column(name = "effective_startdate", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE")
private Date effectiveStartdate;
```

Which I used in my Jpa repository findByXXXLessThanEqual to apply for date condition in my one of the endpoint getmapping method:

```
List<PoJoObject> findByEffectiveStartdateLessThanEqual(Date date);
```

For this entire operation my backend db is postgres and the same field there is having type as TIMESTAMP.

I find out when I called the same get endpoint from client, my query response is not matched with totally passed value which is in the format of yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS instead just yyyy-MM-dd precision is working rest HH:mm:ss.SSS is not effective for the response.

Can anyone help me to findout what went wrong why the passed date in working working as expected.

My client endpoint:

```
http://{{HOST}}/api/v1/operations/greaterthenequal?effectiveStartdate=2019-09-19 17:43:18.683
```

Note:

- using java.util.Date in java code.
- postgres effective_startdate look like this:

> 2019-09-19 18:28:23.012

- method response is also coming in the same format after I changed the @JsonFormat in Entity class

> "effectiveStartdate": "2019-09-19 18:28:23.012"

Comment: I strongly recommend moving to the modern `Instant` in place of `Date`. That alone may fix your problem.

Comment: I got the another error then: findByEffectiveStartdateGreaterThanEqual(java.time.Instant): Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.Instant'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.Instant] for value '2019-09-19 17:43:18.683'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2019-09-19 17:43:18.683]

Comment: Just to note I removed the "@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)" as Instant will not work with Instant.